# Calculate number of battery cycles

Tags: battery-charging, charging, batteries

[Reference paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224188918_Modeling_Lithium_Ion_battery_degradation_in_electric_vehicles)

I need to calculate number of battery cycles. I have all required parameters from formula below, but I am unsure how to do it.

Qnom = the nominal charge capacity of the battery and abs(I) = the absolute value of battery current at a time t. Then the effective number of throughput cycles N in the time interval is given by:

[image]

I(t) is current which was measured per second (Iit has a lot of measurement values), and it has a varying value for both charge and discharge.

Comment: Just add them to a spreadsheet and integrate numerically from time t=0 to t=m, I guess.

Comment: @mkeith [From this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224188918_Modeling_Lithium_Ion_battery_degradation_in_electric_vehicles)

Comment: @mkeith basically I need to take module of the current, integrate it over time and divide by 2 and by nominal capacity per second. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: What form is I(t) in? Do you have a data record of current sampled at regular time intervals?

Comment: @mkeith I(t) is current which was measured per second (Iit has a lot of measurement values), and it has a varying value for both charge and discharge...

Comment: @mkeith sampling period it is continuous, from 1 second to n seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The formula is basically calculating the total charge.

Since you sampled current at 1 second intervals for the duration, it is a simple matter to calculate the integral from the formula. You simply multiply each current sample by 1 second and take the absolute value. The units will be Amp-seconds which is the same as Coulombs.

Add up all the Coulombs from the entire data set, from 1 to n seconds. That is the integral part of the formula. Then divide by the battery capacity (Qnom) in Coulombs. Then divide by 2.

Multiplying by 1 second doesn't change the number, it only changes the units from Amp to Coulomb. So in reality, all you have to do is add up the absolute value of all the current readings in your data set.

Hope that helps.